# Throw 404 when entering website through certain domain?

Tags: .htaccess

There are 3 domains all pointing to the same server, one is main, other is redirecting to the main third should appear as if it doesn't exists.

- Main: website.com
- Redirecting: oldwebsite.com
- Dissappear: testwebsite.com

I've already configured the redirect one, but how can I make sure that when someone enters from `testwebsite.com` he gets standard 404 (pretending like it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this rule as the **very first rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?testwebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

You can also show forbidden error (403) by using:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```